# ASPxGridView: how to handle Close event on client side?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress v.10
I have an ASPxGridView grid on a web page.
I would like to add the following functionality to it. When an EditForm form is being closed (by Cancel button) , I need a message box with warning: 'Do you really want to close the form without saving? Yes/No'

How can I implement this?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Well, I could do this even without the 'custom window'. I can handle CloseButtonClick and Closing events of ASPxPopupControl on client side.

But the problem is: if I change something in an AspxTextBox and then click the Close button immediately, Closing event will be fired FIRST and ValueChanged event will be fired AFTER Closing!

This does not allow me to do what I want.

Is any solution possible here?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to implement and use the Custom Close Button to accomplish this task:

[Find By ID
How to implement a delete confirm dialog with a "don't ask me again" option](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1120.aspx)

[GridViewCommandColumn.CustomButtons Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewCommandColumn_CustomButtonstopic)